# Set layout for the first page of Chapters in ConTeXt

Tags: context

When designing some documents, I hope I can set a global layout and another layout for the first page of all chapters. I have defined two layouts as follows:

```
\setuppagenumbering
[alternative=doublesided,
 location=]

% global layout for the whole document
\setuplayout
[backspace=2.5cm,
 width=16.5cm,
 topspace=2cm,
 height=25.2cm,
 header=\lineheight,
 headerdistance=\lineheight,
 footer=0cm]

% layout for the first page of Chapters
\definelayout
[firstpage]
[height=26.2cm,
 footerdistance=\lineheight,
 footer=\lineheight]

\starttext
\chapter{First Chapter}
I am in the first page.
\page
I am in the second page.
\stoptext
```

Now the question is that how I can apply this `firstpage` layout to the first page of the chapter `First Chapter` and switch back to the `global layout` after the first page of this chapter?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\setuphead` and the `before` key to change the layout
when a new chapter starts. The setting is reset to the default value
when a page is shipped out.

```
\setuppapersize [A6]  %% only for screenshot

\definelayout
  [firstpage]
  [height=8cm]

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [before=\ChapterPageHook]

\starttexdefinition ChapterPageHook
  \appendtoks
    \setuplayout[reset]
  \to\everyshipout
  \setuplayout[firstpage]
\stoptexdefinition

\showframe
\starttext
  \startchapter [title=First Chapter]
  I am in the first page. \page
  I am in the second page.
  \stopchapter

  \startchapter [title=Second Chapter]
  I am in the first page. \page
  I am in the second page.
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: \adpatlayout is  simpler than the \appendtoks jugglary.

Comment: @Aditya \adaptlayout only adjusts the text height. It does not allow to select a different layout, if I'm not mistaken. I tried to simplify the OPs code. Varying the text height probably wasn't the best choice.

Comment: You are right. `\adaptlayout` only checks for `height` and `lines` keys. However, one must use `\setuplayout[reset]` with care. In particular if the main layout is activated using `\definelayout[name][...]` followed by `\setuplayout[name]`, then `\setuplayout[reset]` will reset to default layout rather than `name` layout.

Comment: With `headerdistance=1cm` in the firstpagelayout, the textheight is reduced in all following pages. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Even with this MWE, try replacing the text ("I am…") with `\the\textheight` – the frame is larger, but the area for text is shrunk for all pages

Answer (score 1):

This variant fixes the issue with the area of text pointed out by @tstenner:

```
\setuplayout
[backspace=2.5cm,
 width=16.5cm,
 topspace=2cm,
 height=25.2cm,
 header=\lineheight,
 headerdistance=\lineheight,
 footer=0cm]

\definelayout
  [firstpage]
  [height=8cm]

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [before=\ChapterPageHook]

\starttexdefinition ChapterPageHook
  \setuplayout[firstpage]
    \scratchcounter\pagenumber
    \def\nextPage{\number\numexpr\scratchcounter + 1}
    \definelayout[\nextPage][reset]
\stoptexdefinition

\showframe
\starttext
  \startchapter [title=First Chapter]
  I am in the first page. \input knuth \page
  I am in the second page.\dorecurse{3}{\input knuth}
  \stopchapter

  \startchapter [title=Second Chapter]
  I am in the first page. \input knuth \page
  I am in the second page.\dorecurse{3}{\input knuth}
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

If that that only affects the second page of the chapter, try this. For some reason it makes the layout change stick.

```
\def\nnextPage{\number\numexpr\scratchcounter + 2}
\definelayout[\nnextPage][reset]
```