# ConTeXt: Defining layout of specific pages

Tags: context

I would like to specify in advance that certain pages are to have different layouts, specifically, that the first page should have a bigger header than the rest of the pages pages.

Based on the [Wiki article](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout#Multiple_layouts), this should be accomplished with something like:

```
% different layout for first two pages
\definelayout[1][wide]
\definelayout[3][reset]
```

However, when I put together my own MWE, it doesn't behave as expected. Rather than setting only the first page to have a big header, I somehow end up setting all pages to have a big header, except for the second.

```
\setuppapersize[A6]

\definelayout[bigheader][header=0.5\textheight]
\definelayout[smallheader][header=0.1\textheight]

\setuplayout[smallheader]
\definelayout[1][bigheader]
\definelayout[2][smallheader]

\starttext
\showframe
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image: output]

Can someone explain what's going wrong?

I'm also aware of [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126732/141419) but it seems overly complex for just setting the layout of the first page and that's it.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but if you remove the `\definelayout[2][smallheadings]` line, then the settings revert back to normal after page 1

Comment: @Aditya Thanks, that does seem to work for the MWE. I can't seem to reproduce my actual problem where the settings refuse to revert to default, but I guess `\definelayout[2][smallheadings]` isn't the way to go.

Comment: @Aditya Mind writing an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the code in the MWE is not working. One possible fix is to remove `\definelayout[2][smallheadings]`. For example:

```
\setuppapersize[A6]

\definelayout[bigheader][header=0.5\textheight]
\definelayout[smallheader][header=0.1\textheight]

\setuplayout[smallheader]
\definelayout[1][bigheader]

\starttext
\showframe
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\stoptext
```