# ConTeXt: How to change parts and chapters pages background color with MetaFun?

Tags: sectioning, context, metafun

I am trying to reproduce something like this for parts and chapters with MetaFun:

[image: Screenshot from 'Get Programming with F#' by Isaac Abraham]

Placing the content on the page is simple so I am trying to get the colored background. However I do not know how to have it on the *whole* page...

My first attempt was to setup an `alternative` with an `MPpage`:

```tex
\setuppapersize[A6][A6]
\startsetups[partHeadRendering]
  \startMPpage
    StartPage ;

    numeric w ; w := bbwidth(Page) ;
    numeric h ; h := bbheight(Page) ;

    fill (unitsquare xyscaled (w,h)) withcolor \MPcolor{darkred} ;
    StopPage ;
  \stopMPpage
\stopsetups

\defineheadalternative[partrenderer][alternative=vertical, renderingsetup=partHeadRendering]


\setuphead[part][alternative=partrenderer, placehead=yes]

\showframe
\starttext
  \startpart
  \stoppart
\stoptext
```

But...

[image]

Then I tried to use `MPgraphic` with an `overlay` as shown in [the cover page wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Cover_Pages#First_one)

```tex
\setuppapersize[A6][A6]

\startuseMPgraphic{PartCover}
  \startMPpage
    StartPage ;
    fill Page withcolor \MPcolor{darkred} ;
    StopPage ;
  \stopMPpage
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[PartCover][\useMPgraphic{PartCover}]

\startsetups[partHeadRendering]
  \setupbackgrounds[page][background=PartCover]
\stopsetups

\defineheadalternative[partrenderer][alternative=vertical, renderingsetup=partHeadRendering]


\setuphead[part][alternative=partrenderer, placehead=yes]

\showframe
\starttext
  \startpart
  \stoppart
\stoptext
```

but it did not go well either...

[image]

I also did take a look at this [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126732/213111) but I got the same result as the first one.

Comment: Just a question: Do "Lesson 1" and "The visual studio experience" both belong to the same section level? Or is "Lesson 1" a part and "The visual studio experience" a chapter?

Comment: They both belong to the same section level.

Comment: Why don't you try with the `eso-pic` package?

Comment: @Bernard This question is about ConTeXt.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I should have read all details in the question…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have learned today that you can work with a `partpage` mode and a layer that is only filled with content for part pages. Something like the following.

Define the MetaFun background:

```
\startuseMPgraphic{part}
StartPage ;
  fill Page withcolor 0.25[white,darkcyan] ;
  picture p, q ;
  p := textext("\ss\bf\setstrut\strut\getmarking[partnumber]") scaled 14 ;
  q := textext("\ss\bf\setstrut\strut Lesson") scaled 2 ;

  p := (p shifted - center p) ;
  q := (q shifted - center q) ;

  draw image (
    draw p withcolor white ;
    draw q ;
  ) shifted urcorner Field[Text][Text]  shifted - urcorner p ;
StopPage ;
\stopuseMPgraphic
```

Define a layer, an overlay (that uses a `\directsetup` that is introduced in the next step), and set the background to use them.

```
\definelayer[part][width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]
\defineoverlay[pagebackground][\directsetup{pagebackground}]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=pagebackground]
```

Add the just mentioned setup. It checks if you are in the `partpage`, and if you are, it updates the content of the layer with `\setlayer`, and then it disables the `partpage` mode (if not, you will get the layer on the upcoming pages as well). Then place the layer.

```
\startsetups pagebackground
\doifelsemode {partpage} {
  \setlayer[part][preset=lefttop]{\useMPgraphic{part}}
  \globaldisablemode[partpage]
  }{}
\placelayer[part]
\stopsetups
```

We add another setup that enables the partpage mode and pushes the content of the part page.

```
\startsetups part:before
\globalenablemode[partpage]
\blank[force,20*line]
\stopsetups
```

Finally we set up the part. The important thing for us here is the `before` key that enables the `partpage` mode so that the pagebackground kicks in. I added also a `style`.

```
\setuphead[part][
  number=no,
  placehead=yes,
  header=high,
  before=\setup{part:before},
  style={\definedfont[SansBold at 18pt]\WORD},
]
```

Then we are ready for content. I switched font to dejavu, but you of course have another favorite to use.

```
\setupbodyfont[dejavu]

\starttext
\startpart[title={The visual studio experience}]
  \dorecurse{20}{\samplefile{ward}}
\stoppart
\stoptext
```

Adding all this together gives the following first two pages.

[image: the first two pages showing the result]

**Edit**

Two comments. The code

```
\startuseMPgraphic{PartCover}
  \startMPpage
    StartPage ;
    fill Page withcolor \MPcolor{darkred} ;
    StopPage ;
  \stopMPpage
\stopuseMPgraphic
```

that you suggest is invalid. If `\startMPpage` and `\stopMPpage` are removed it will look better.

Additionally, there is a [testsuite](http://www.pragma-ade.com/download-1.htm) that contains a lot of nice examples. In this specific case the `toggles-001.tex` in the backgrounds folder.

Comment: Impressive! Thank you! Can I ask you where did you find that out and where I can learn more about it?

Comment: I updated with a link to the testsuite (Hans pointed me in that direction)

Comment: Just to have a complete answer to the question: you stated that you use chapters instead of parts here. Let's say I want to reuse this for parts, does it means that I just have to replace every occurrence of `chapter` with `part`? But when I do this, it does not seems to work. I guess I miss something obvious. Anyway, thank you very much for this!

Comment: Ah, then one needs `placehead=yes`. I'll update.

Comment: Oh, of course! Stupid me! It works perfectly!

Comment: I'm reusing your answer to a section I have created. When I comment out `\globaldisablemode[mysectionpage]` in your `pagebackground` setup the background applied to the whole `mysection`. This is great. However, the background never ends and continues when exiting the `mysection`. I thought that putting `\globaldisablemode[mysectionpage]` in the else part of the `\doifelsemode` would do the trick but it seems it does not work like that. Do you know what should I do?

Comment: Not sure I get what you are trying to do. Can you please ask a new question (you can link to this question) and explain more. Perhaps by showing your code and what you get, it will be easier to understand.