# ConTeXT: Two pages only background for an head

Tags: context

In order to finish my whole `background` series, I am trying to figure out how to set the background for only the first two pages of heads (`part`, `chapter`, whatever). Here is an example I found from a french book

[image]

As you can see, the first two pages could probably be a super head level with the "two pages background" (or just a SVG graphic, but let's say it is not) and then, the part and chapter pages are back to `default` background.
This is what I am currently trying to get.

To do that I have investigate through some links : first of all, a [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641431/213111) of [mickep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/52406/mickep) allowing me to change the background of the first page of the structure.
Without any real modification, this is what we get from it:

```tex
\definemeasure[PartPaperWidth][\paperwidth]
\definemeasure[PartPaperHeight][\paperheight]

\startuseMPgraphic{PartBackgroundGraphic}
  path background;
  background := origin -- (2*\measure{PartPaperWidth},0cm) --
                          (2*\measure{PartPaperWidth},\measure{PartPaperHeight}) --
                          (0cm,\measure{PartPaperHeight}) --
                cycle ;
  fill background withcolor 0.3[white,red] ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definelayer[PartBackgroundLayer][width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]
\defineoverlay[PartBackgroundOverlay][\directsetup{PartBackgroundSetup}]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=PartBackgroundOverlay]

\startsetups PartBackgroundSetup
\doifelsemode {partpage} {
  \setlayer[PartBackgroundLayer][preset=lefttop]{\useMPgraphic{PartBackgroundGraphic}}
  \globaldisablemode[partpage]
  }{}
\placelayer[PartBackgroundLayer]
\stopsetups

\startsetups part:before
\globalenablemode[partpage]
\stopsetups

\setuphead[part][
  number=no,
  placehead=yes,
  header=high,
  before=\setup{part:before},
]

\starttext
\startpart[title={An awesome title}]
  \dorecurse{20}{\samplefile{ward}}

\startpart[title={An awesome title}]
  \dorecurse{20}{\samplefile{ward}}
\stoppart
\stoptext
```

[image]

As one can observes, we only do get the left part of the graphic on the left page and the right part of the graphic does not appear on the right page.

In order to do that, I tried the following from [Wolfgang Schuster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/33961/wolfgang-schuster) and [Dave Jarvis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2148/dave-jarvis) in [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524759/213111) which allows me to span the background on two pages.

To implement that in my case I changed a little bit of the `PartBackgroundSetup`, like so

```tex
\startsetups PartBackgroundSetup
\doifelsemode {partpage} {
  \setlayer[PartBackgroundLayer][y=.0\paperheight]
    {\clip[nx=2,x=\doifelseoddpage{1}{2}]
      {\useMPgraphic{PartBackgroundGraphic}}}
    \globaldisablemode[partpage]
  }{}
\placelayer[PartBackgroundLayer]
\stopsetups
```

Then, there is two possible output depending if I do use or if I do not use `\globaldisablemode[partpage]`.
If I do use it I get

[image]

and if I do not use it I get

[image]

At some point [Aditya](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) [gives me an idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659281/213111): what if I use a page counter to exit `partmode` after the second page? Yeah, it sounds great, let's do that!

```tex
\definecounter[PartPageCounter][way=bypage]

\startsetups PartBackgroundSetup
\doifelsemode {partpage} {
  \setlayer[PartBackgroundLayer][y=.0\paperheight]
    {\clip[nx=2,x=\doifelseoddpage{1}{2}]
      {\useMPgraphic{PartBackgroundGraphic}}}
    \ifnum\rawcountervalue[PartPageCounter]>2\globaldisablemode[partmode]\fi
  }{}
\placelayer[PartBackgroundLayer]
\stopsetups

\startsetups part:before
\globalenablemode[partpage]
\setcounter[PartPageCounter][1]
\stopsetups
```

and... it did not work.

How can I make that background appears only on the first two pages of a new head (`part`, `chapter`, etc.)?

Comment: Maybe you can use [`\startpostponing`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startpostponing)?

Comment: You are not incrementing the counter! But even if you did, `way=bypage` means that the counter gets reset at every page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea: At the start of every page, save the value of `\realpageno` at the beginning of each section, and then disable the `partpage` mode whenever  `\realpageno=\LastPart+2`.

```
\definemeasure[PartPaperWidth][\paperwidth]
\definemeasure[PartPaperHeight][\paperheight]

\startuseMPgraphic{PartBackgroundGraphic}
  path background;
  background := origin -- (2*\measure{PartPaperWidth},0cm) --
                          (2*\measure{PartPaperWidth},\measure{PartPaperHeight}) --
                          (0cm,\measure{PartPaperHeight}) --
                cycle ;
  fill background withcolor 0.3[white,red] ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definelayer[PartBackgroundLayer][width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]
\defineoverlay[PartBackgroundOverlay][\directsetup{PartBackgroundSetup}]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=PartBackgroundOverlay]

\permanent\countdef\LastPart\zerocount

\startsetups PartBackgroundSetup
\doif{\the\realpageno}{\the\numexpr\LastPart+2\relax}
  {\globaldisablemode[partpage]}
\doifelsemode {partpage} {
  \setlayer[PartBackgroundLayer][y=.0\paperheight]
    {\clip[nx=2,x=\doifelseoddpage{1}{2}]
      {\useMPgraphic{PartBackgroundGraphic}}}
  }{}
\placelayer[PartBackgroundLayer]
\stopsetups

\startsetups part:before
\globalenablemode[partpage]
\LastPart=\realpageno\relax
\stopsetups

\setuphead[part][
  number=no,
  placehead=yes,
  header=high,
  before=\setup{part:before},
]

\starttext
\startpart[title={An awesome title}]
  \dorecurse{40}{\samplefile{ward}}

\startpart[title={An awesome title}]
  \dorecurse{40}{\samplefile{ward}}
\stoppart
\stoptext
```